# Regex to replace and get updated string

Tags: javascript, replace

I have following string:

`style="width: 100%; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;letter-spacing: 1px;"`

I want to generate it like

`style={{'width': '100%'; 'max-width': '800px'; 'margin': '0 auto';'letter-spacing': '1px';"`

With regex replace. Also I have these styling in entire page of HTML

I tried following

`style="(.*): (.*);`

Comment: If you are using JavaScript that supports a quantifier in the lookbehind `(?<=\bstyle="[^"]*)\b([^\s:;]+)\s*:\s+([^;+]+)` https://regex101.com/r/PhvTyX/1 and then you can do a second replacement for `style=` --> `style{{`

Comment: Sounds like you want to convert HTML to React. If that's the case, you may want to use [the built-in HTML parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to parse the string into an actual element, then iterate over its [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property.

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird I was able to achieve it by your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this with a regular expression is going to be a difficult task. For instance, a CSS value may contain a `;` character, like here:

```css
background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7)
```

Also CSS properties can have parentheses that must be balanced, and quoted strings, like:

```css
background: cross-fade(20% url('first.png'), url("second.png"));
```

To correctly identify where a value starts and ends is thus not trivial.

An alternative is to use a DOM Parser. In JavaScript you can use `DOMParser`, and then put the style string as an HTML attribute, and read back the `style` property from the DOM. This will give you the list of CSS attributes that have been explicitly set on the element, and their corresponding values.

This may be in a more elaborate format than in the original string, giving individual CSS attributes, where the original string may have used a higher level, combining attribute, but the meaning will be equivalent.

Here is how that works on your example:

```js
function convert(s) {
    const [{style}] = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<br ${s}>`, "text/html").body.children;
    const obj = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(style, prop => [prop, style[prop]])); 
    return `style={${JSON.stringify(obj)}}`;
}

const s = 'style="width: 100%; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;letter-spacing: 1px;"';
const result = convert(s);

console.log(result);
```